# Password reset message - change the network_home_url( '/' )

Tags: password, reset

I would like to change the usual message sent by WordPress which says the following:

Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:
http://myexample.com/

I know that this comes from wp-login.php which has the following lines:

```
$message = __('Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= network_home_url( '/' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Is there any way I can change $message .= network_home_url( '/' ) to
http://myexample.com/member by adding something in functions.php perhaps?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's [check the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_home_url) and follow the links to [the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3029):

```
3029    function network_home_url( $path = '', $scheme = null ) {
3030            if ( ! is_multisite() )
3031                    return home_url($path, $scheme);
3032    
3033            $current_site = get_current_site();
3034            $orig_scheme = $scheme;
3035    
3036            if ( ! in_array( $scheme, array( 'http', 'https', 'relative' ) ) )
3037                    $scheme = is_ssl() && ! is_admin() ? 'https' : 'http';
3038    
3039            if ( 'relative' == $scheme )
3040                    $url = $current_site->path;
3041            else
3042                    $url = set_url_scheme( 'http://' . $current_site->domain . $current_site->path, $scheme );
3043    
3044            if ( $path && is_string( $path ) )
3045                    $url .= ltrim( $path, '/' );
3046    
3047            /**
3048             * Filter the network home URL.
3049             *
3050             * @since 3.0.0
3051             *
3052             * @param string      $url         The complete network home URL including scheme and path.
3053             * @param string      $path        Path relative to the network home URL. Blank string
3054             *                                 if no path is specified.
3055        https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3029     * @param string|null $orig_scheme Scheme to give the URL context. Accepts 'http', https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3029'https',
3056             *                                 'relative' or null.
3057             */
3058            return apply_filters( 'network_home_url', $url, $path, $orig_scheme);
3059    }
```

We see that, yes, there is a filter called `network_home_url` that we can use to alter the link. A simple filter such as the following would do it, though I doubt you want something this simplified in practice:

```
function alter_net_link_wpse_206603($url, $path, $orig_scheme) {
  return 'http://myexample.com/member';
}
add_filter('network_home_url','alter_net_link_wpse_206603',10,3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just unsure as to what you mean by saying that you doubt I want something this simply in practice? Is is unsafe to use this for the password reset message? Or should I alter $message .= network_home_url( '/' ) . "\r\n\r\n"; in another way?

Comment: You are changing an important address without checking for context. That is a cause for concern.

Comment: In that case I'd rather not use it but is there any way I can change the message that is specified in wp-login.php as follows: `$message = __('Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:') . "\r\n\r\n";
 $message .= network_home_url( '/' ) . "\r\n\r\n";`

Comment: I had to reword my question and post a new question.